# Sum results from a pivot to get monthly sales of produtcs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm writing a query to get results of monthly sales, I'm just missing a column to sum the total sales of all months.

https://dbfiddle.uk/oIclJV3u

Query:

```
create table sales(
    itemcode INT, name varchar(255), amount decimal(18,2), salesdate date);
insert into sales (itemcode, name, amount, salesdate)
values
(01, 'product1', 01, '2023-10-01'),
(01, 'product1', 5, '2023-11-03'),
(02, 'product1', 10, '2023-11-10')

SELECT * FROM (SELECT YEAR(SalesDate) [YEAR], DATENAME(MONTH, SalesDate) [Month], COUNT(1) [Amount Count], itemcode, Name FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(SalesDate), DATENAME(MONTH, SalesDate), itemcode, Name) AS MonthlyDates
PIVOT (SUM([Amount COUNT])
FOR MONTH IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) as MNAMEPIVOT
```

Results in this:

| year | itemcode | Name | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 01 | product1 | NULL | 10 | 5 | 1 | NULL | 10 | 2 | 5 | 10 | 9 | 10 | 1 |
| 2023 | 02 | product2 | 5 | 100 | NULL | 65 | 10 | 32 | NULL | 8 | 89 | 6 | 46 | 2 |
| 2023 | 03 | product3 | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 20 | NULL | 12 | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023 | 04 | product4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023 | 05 | product5 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 5 | 41 | 12 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Desired result:

| year | itemcode | Name | January | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 01 | product1 | NULL | 10 | 5 | 1 | NULL | 10 | 2 | 5 | 10 | 9 | 10 | 1 | 91 |
| 2023 | 02 | product2 | 5 | 100 | NULL | 65 | 10 | 32 | NULL | 8 | 89 | 6 | 46 | 2 | 454 |
| 2023 | 03 | product3 | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 20 | NULL | 12 | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 40 |
| 2023 | 04 | product4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 |
| 2023 | 05 | product5 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 5 | 41 | 12 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 92 |

Comment: please provide also the original tables with the data that produce the result table

Comment: i edited the original post with the table schema

Comment: you are stillmmissing the data that produces the result you posted, ideally as dbfiddle see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: db fiddle added

Comment: Question needs to be self contained, please add sample data directly into the questions.

Comment: done, sample added.

Comment: The sample data you have provided doesn't match your desired results.

Comment: Why can't you perform the summation and display it at your presentation layer ?

Comment: @Squirrel im working 100% with management studio and it will provide me with more info/knowledge about how will or should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant way of doing it and to be honest this kind of things should really be done in the presentation layer (e.g. in your report) but anyway..

You can just UNION the year totals in your subquery can fix the name as 'Total' then just add this new *month* to the pivot expression.

```
drop table if exists #sales
create table #sales(
  itemcode INT, name varchar(255), amount decimal(18,2), salesdate date);
insert into #sales (itemcode, name, amount, salesdate) values (01, 'product1', 01, '2023-10-01'),
(01, 'product1', 5, '2023-11-03'),
(02, 'product1', 10, '2023-11-10')

SELECT * 
  FROM (
       SELECT YEAR(SalesDate) [YEAR], 
              DATENAME(MONTH, SalesDate) [Month], 
              COUNT(1) [Amount Count], 
              itemcode, 
              Name 
       FROM #Sales
       GROUP BY YEAR(SalesDate), DATENAME(MONTH, SalesDate), itemcode, Name
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT YEAR(SalesDate) [YEAR], 
              'Total' [Month], 
              COUNT(1) [Amount Count], 
              itemcode, 
              Name 
       FROM #Sales
       GROUP BY YEAR(SalesDate), itemcode, Name  
       ) AS MonthlyDates
  PIVOT (SUM([Amount Count])
   FOR MONTH IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
      [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
      [December],
      [Total])
  ) as MNAMEPIVOT
```

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: You hit the nail sir, well done.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to extract the month from the *salesdate* variable, and then use a GROUP BY function to sum up the sales amount by month.

Firstly, a separate variable can be created as follows:

```
alter table sales add month int;
```

The month can then be extracted:

```
update sales set month=extract(month from salesdate);
```

Sales can then be grouped by month and name. Based on the sample data you provided, the results are as follows:

```
select month, name, sum(amount)
from sales
group by month, name
order by month;
```

```
 month |   name   |  sum  
-------+----------+-------
    10 | product1 |  1.00
    11 | product1 | 15.00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: OP is using `SQL Server`